# AngularJS $sce only trust certain elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngsanitize

Assume the following string:

```
<b><i><anotherelement>Hello World</anotherelement></i></b>
```

I only want to allow the bold element to work, while the italic element (and any other elements!) remains untouched, so the output is:
**`<i><anotherelement>Hello World</anotherelement></i>`**.

Currently I use:

```
function outputHtml($element, value){
  $element.html($sanitize(value));
}
```

That solution trusts all elements that come with the $sce bundle so it's not useful for me :(

Any help will be appreciated,
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3J25M/764/

Controller -

```
angular.module('ngBindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('ngBindHtmlCtrl', ['$scope','$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.value = '<i><anotherelement>Hello World</anotherelement></i>';
    $scope.myHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b ng-bind="value"></b>');
}])
.directive('compileTemplate', function($compile, $parse){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
            function getStringValue() {
                return (parsed(scope) || '').toString();
            }

            // Recompile if the template changes
            scope.$watch(getStringValue, function() {
                $compile(element, null, -9999)(scope);  // The -9999 makes it skip directives so that we do not recompile ourselves
            });
        }
    }
});
```

HTML -

```
<div ng-app="ngBindHtmlExample">
    <div ng-controller="ngBindHtmlCtrl">
        <p ng-bind-html="myHTML" compile-template></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Doesn't exactly solve it, because I need to pass the string as a whole to the $scope.value (including the <b>). But thanks anyway!

Comment: welcome, i am sure you will figure out that, as there are many possibilities and that depends on your exact requirement, one being using substring and extracting only inner HTML to provide it to `$scope.value`